# android App Chosser RuntimeExeption Error

Tags: android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello and thank you in advance.
Currently I want to make use of the ROS applications form the android marketplace (ROS App Chooser and Make a Map) but I had encounter some problems trying to connect to the robot. I'm using a Galaxy tab 10.1 (3.2) ubuntu version 11.10 ROS Electric. I have the multi master stack installed as well as the pr2 applications and I'm currently using the pr2_app_manager for testing. I have no problems running my launcher nor running the services of the application manager through terminal. My problem starts when I'm connecting to my robot once the URI is added into the App Chooser of my tab and I get the following error message.

Failed: cannot contact robot:org.ros.exeption.
RemoteException: org.ros.exception.RosRuntimeException:
Connection exception:oscar-MS-7576:36846

I still able to see the "App Manager" button and the "ROS Exchange" button but every time I click on those I get the same error.
What do you think might be my problem? Hope anyone could help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34363/android-app-chosser-runtimeexeption-error/) by [Oscar117](https://answers.ros.org/users/2413/oscar117/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-05-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sounds like a networking problem. Often times NAT or a firewall makes the connection one way between the robot and the android device. You can test this by pinging the device from the computer. Check the settings of the device to find the IP.

---

Originally posted by [tpratkanis_wg](https://answers.ros.org/users/927/tpratkanis_wg/) with karma: 56 on 2012-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0